# React-text-mask not formatting the input value into Indian Currency Format

Tags: reactjs

I'm using react-text-mask for masking the input field. Input field should format the user input into valid Indian currency format.

I have been trying the following code but this doesn't help.

```
<MaskedInput
          mask={[
            /\d{1,2}/,
            /\d{1,2}/,
            ",",
            ")",
            " ",
            /\d/,
            /\d/,
            /\d/,
            "-",
            /\d/,
            /\d/,
            /\d/,
            /\d/,
          ]}
        />
```

input: `213456`

output displayed synchronously should be: `2,13,456`

input: `222345666.956`

output displayed synchronously should be: `22,23,45,666.956`

---

Any help on how to achieve Indian currency formatting in react would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

You don't need a library for this. Just use toLocaleString like this.

`console.log((123123123.11).toLocaleString('hi'));`

Comment: yes this can be used but to use this i have to implement a state variable for  input value and as setState  method is not synchronous,its creating issue in every change triggered on user input.